# PEAR Mail Queue Database Explaination

Tags: php, pear

I recently set up a mail queue server to help with an issue sending a newsletter to 600+ recipients, which though untested at that volume, it should do the job... hopefully.

However during testing I noticed that a recipient got stuck in the queue and wouldn't send, the problem seemed to be that the `try_sent` field in the database was set to 25, whereas the rest were 0 (I think this was after a while of letting it try to send during construction and with some coding errors, so probably didn't start out as 25 when initially inserted). When I changed it back to 0, it sent fine. What does `try_sent` actually mean in this context (is it an error code or an increment of how many times an attempt to send it has been made, or something else?).

The majority of the fields are relatively self explanatory, but I'd like to know what some relate to so I know what's going on.

The fields are:

```
time_to_send - same as create_time - can you setup a send delay?
sent_time - guess it'd show when sent if not deleted from queue on send
id_user - ? (set to -1 when added)
ip - seems to be IP of the server that ran the add script ie. my IP
try_sent - ¿que?
```

any light that could be shed on this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Look in Mail/Queue.php:

> define('MAILQUEUE_TRY', 25);
>   This constant tells Mail_Queue how many times should try to send mails again if was any errors before.